# Events calendar that can be sent in html email newsletter?

Tags: html, email, events, calendar, newsletter

I'm looking for a calendar - something like http://time.ly - that can be included in an html email newsletter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is a service for this.

There are however several solutions for RSS feeds in html email, perhaps if your calendar could be outputted to RSS, you could list it on the page like this [linear calendar example from time.ly](http://www.happeninginaspen.com/?ai1ec=action%3Astream)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to generate a .ics file and attach it to your email. Most of the email  client (like Gmail) can find it and display as a part of email body. Usually, it will has an "add to calendar" link which is generated by email client for this .ics file (like Gmail).

Here is a reference to .ics file format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar